# Pandas: filtering DataFrame rows based on values in another series

Tags: pandas, filter, series

I have a DataFrame like such:

```
id, fruit
1, apple
1, kiwi
2, melon
2, kiwi
3, mango
3, melon
3, mango
```

I have a Pandas Series like such:

```
id, fruit
1, apple
2, kiwi
3, mango
```

I want to filter my DataFrame such that for each row, its 'fruit' matches the corresponding value in the Series. For id=1, since fruit in series is apple, it filters only rows with fruit apple. For id=2, since fruit in series is kiwi, it filters only rows with fruit kiwi. For id=3, since fruit in series is mango, it filters only rows with fruit mango. I want:

```
id, fruit
1, apple
2, kiwi
3, mango
3, mango
```

Any suggestions?

*edit because it was incorrectly marked as an existing question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ hey, I think you incorrectly marked my question as an existing question. The question you linked to is not a solution to my question.

Comment: @COLDSPEED please

Comment: Are you sure?  `df[df.fruit.isin(df2.fruit.tolist())]`

Comment: yes, I edited my dataframe to make my example more specific: added (1, kiwi). Here, (1, kiwi) is not populated in the filtered dataframe because the key-value pair of id=1 is (id=1,fruit=apple) as specified in the series. sorry, my initial example was not specific enough.

Comment: So both the column _and_ id need to match?

Comment: In that case, do something like `df.merge(df2)`